# Linearity of Fourier transformation.

Tags: probability-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

Let $\rho$ be a representation of a finite group $G$, and let $P$ and $Q$ be probabilities on $G$. Prove $\widehat{P*Q}(\rho)=\hat{P}(\rho)\hat{Q}(\rho)$

I know that by definition, $\hat{P}(\rho)=\sum_{s}P(s)\rho(s)$, $\hat{Q}(\rho)=\sum_{t}Q(t)\rho(t)$ and $P*Q(\rho)=\sum_{t\in G}P(st^{-1})Q(t)=\sum_{s\in G}P(t)Q(t^{-1}s)$, but I'm not sure how to manipulate this to let both side equal.

Answer (score 1):

Notice

$$ \widehat{P\ast Q}(\rho)=\sum_{s} (P\ast Q)(s)\rho(s)=\sum_s\left(\sum_{ab=s} P(a)Q(b)\right)\rho(s)=\sum_{a,b} P(a)Q(b)\rho(ab). $$

Then, using $\rho(ab)=\rho(a)\rho(b)$, we can factore this double summation as a product of sums:

$$ =\left(\sum_a P(a)\rho(a)\right)\left(\sum_b Q(b)\rho(b)\right)=\widehat{P}(\rho)\widehat{Q}(\rho). $$

Comment: Shouldn't the summation in the inside be over a different variable? So, $\sum_{t}P(st^{-1})Q(t)$?

Comment: also, I'm struggling to understand how showing $\widehat{P*Q}(\rho)=\hat{P}(a)\hat{Q}(b)$ is equivalent. to showing $\widehat{P*Q}(\rho)=\hat{P}(\rho)\hat{Q}(\rho)$

Comment: @YaG For your first comment, $\sum_{ab=s}P(a)Q(b)$ and $\sum_t P(st^{-1})Q(t)$ are the same summation. Notice that $(st^{-1},t)$, as $t$ ranges over the group, covers exactly all possible pairs $(a,b)$ of group elements such that $ab=s$. (That's a more natural way of thinking about what convolving two functions does with them.) If you want, you can think of it as a reindexing. As for your second comment, thanks for pointing out the typo.